How to execute zsh commands inside nvim command line?
I know this is a noob question but I cant seem to find an answer in the internet.
I want to execute zsh commands inside the nvim command line. I want to set this up so that I can copy current directory's / file's path I'm currently editing.
Basically I have .zshrc file containing my alias commands. For example...
alias CopyDir="pwd | xclip -selection clipboard"

This command works when executed in terminal, but doesn't work when run in nvim command line. Eg...
:! CopyDir

returns - zsh:1: command not found: CopyDir\ shell returned 127
I can't seem to find any info online about it. Either its impossible, its not widely needed, or I've missed out the command to achieve this in a much easier way. I've been using vim mode for about half a year now so I've been slowly transferring to nvim as my IDE of choice. Been loving the experience so far, just need more experience, and more knowledge on set up.

:! zsh -c "CopyDir"

@GhorbanM.Tavakoly Yeah I've tried that too. It doesn't work. It returns the same error. I should actually look more into this error.

I've looked through what the Error code might mean and I've made sure that their isn't any dependency issues / permission issues.
So whats left is Shell Config issue that's resulting in the command not being found.
Do I have to connect nvim and zsh in some way for the commands to be found by nvim?

I'm in emacs league and not deep dived in vim. but i think using coc.nvim with zsh language server may help. for example: https://github.com/tjdevries/coc-zsh

Does :! zsh -ic CopyDir work?

To run zsh commands in the nvim/vim command line, try these:

Use zsh -c:

:! zsh -c "ZSHCOMMAND"


Alternatively, try zsh -ic:

:! zsh -ic "ZSHCOMMAND"

Just swap out ZSHCOMMAND with the command you want to run.

Alias is only works in interactive sessions.
to make your alias works you must write executable file and put it on one of your $PATH.
or simply do this instead:
" copying file dir
:!echo %:p:~:h | xclip

" copying file path
:!echo %:p:~ | xclip

